# How to JSON.parse ignoring suffix after object

Tags: javascript, json, jsonparser

I have an input string

```
let input = '{"username": "John Doe", "email": "john@example.com"} trailing text'
```

I want to `JSON.parse` it, but it fails because of trailing text.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token t in JSON at position 54
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6
```

How could I parse JSON object from this text ignoring trailing text?

Comment: Are there any limitations on what characters may exist in the trailing text?

Comment: @Gershy no limitations, there could be any text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse it once, extract the error position from the error message, chop off everything from that position on and parse again. Pretty lame, but works (mostly).

```js
let input = '{"username": "John Doe", "email": "john@example.com"} trailing text'


try {
    JSON.parse(input)
} catch(e) {
    let m = e.message.match(/position\s+(\d+)/)
    if (m)
        input = input.slice(0, m[1])
}


result = JSON.parse(input)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Only downsides are that the error's text may not be standardized, and it will be difficult to differentiate between an error resulting from a genuine syntax error as opposed to one only caused by the trailing text

Comment: @Gershy: yes, parsing the error message is extremely lame, but with built-in JSON there seems to be no other way.

Answer (score 1):

If you hate your cpu you can apply `JSON.parse` repeatedly to your input, but after each attempt remove the last character:

```js
let parseJsonWithArbitrarySuffix = str => {
  
  while (str) {
    try { return JSON.parse(str); } catch(err) {}
    str = str.slice(0, -1);
  }
  
  throw new Error(`Invalid input`);
  
};

let input = '{"username": "John Doe", "email": "john@example.com"} trailing text';
console.log(parseJsonWithArbitrarySuffix(input));
```

Comment: Please use @georg's answer and not this one :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
let input = '{"username": "John Doe", "email": "john@example.com"} trailing text'

input = input.slice(0, input.lastIndexOf('}') + 1)

JSON.parse(input)
```

This removes everything after the final }

Comment: The issue here is that arrays, strings, numbers, `true`, `false`, and `null` are all valid `JSON.parse` inputs, not to mention that the trailing text may happen to contain the delimiter `}` by coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

I searched dozens of npm packages and tried many regex expressions. Eventually I turned to AI and it told me to hand-craft a JSON parser. I got fed up with this issue and [hand-crafted a JSON parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/obvious-json). To anyone who finds this answer, you're welcome.